# Any Alternative of Image Resizer To Resize Images within the Web Page?

Tags: php, image, image-processing

I have facilitated the users of my site to post external images in their comments. But some of the image size could be more than the size of my webpage. To keep the images within the boundary of webpage, I searched on google and found a tool named **[Image Resizer](http://www.sevenskins.com/vbulletin-hacks/image-resizer.html)** But it works only with Vbulletin forums. I do not want to actually cut down the size of an image, I just want if the width of an image size is more than the width of webpage, then the tool should set its width to my specific given width and the height accordingly. Any alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank God. I have found the Solution. The Solution is very simple, but It took me too much time to find it.

I just changed my CSS a little and no need to use any Third Party Tool.

```
img
{
   max-width:100%;
   display:block;
   border:none;
}
```

And the Problem is solved. All the Images larger than the webpage are within the webpage and the smaller images are as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting '**width:100%;height:100%**' in the CSS of that Image. It works for me.

Comment: What if the image size is less than the webpage. Suppose my webpage is 1000px wide and the image size is 300px wide, then the image will become wider to 1000px using 100%. I only want to keep the images those are larger than the webpage size.

Answer (score 0):

in image tage you can Determine width and height like this

```
 <img src="http://www.hh4track.com/images/logo.png" width="100px" height="100px" />
```

or you can rezise the image with this class

```
 http://kazymjir.com/blog/image-resizing-php-class/
```